# Batch resize one image in multiple sizes with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm on Windows 10 with PowerShell and I'm trying to batch resize one image in multiple sizes with ImageMagick running the following command:

for i in 554 612 640 664 706 728 750 780 828 856 1536 1668 2048; do mogrify -resize "$i" -write portrait"$i".jpg 2048.jpg; done

554 612 640 664 706 728 750 780 828 856 1536 1668 2048 are the widths I want to resize my image to while preserving the aspect ratio;
my input image name is '2048.jpg';
and the output of running this code are .jpg files named: portrait554.jpg, portrait612.jpg, portrait640.jpg, and so on for each dimension.

Unfortunately I get this error:
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword

And unfortunately I'm not very good with command line to understand what I'm doing wrong. Somebody can help me, please?

Comment: See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#write. On Windows remove the \ before parentheses and change the end of line \ to ^. I am not sure what else you need for Powershell.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 I've tried your solution but in the end I've decided to use convert on each line and I'm posting below what it's working now on my end, in case someone need it

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution working with Windows 10 and PowerShell, in case someone need it. I've decided to use convert instead of mogrify - cause mogrify potentially deletes the file processed, and also with convert I can process one file at the time if I want to - and I've applied the best jpeg optimization settings I've found, and also for webp. Here's the commands.

cd to your directory and then:

magick convert 2048x2732.jpg -format jpeg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 80 -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -colorspace RGB -write 2048.jpg
magick convert 2048x2732.jpg -resize 1668 -format jpeg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 80 -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -colorspace RGB -write 1668.jpg
magick convert 2048x2732.jpg -resize 1536 -format jpeg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 80 -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -colorspace RGB -write 1536.jpg
...
null:

magick convert 2048x2732.jpg -format webp -quality 80 -write 2048.webp
magick convert 2048x2732.jpg -resize 1668 -format webp -quality 80 -write 1668.webp
magick convert 2048x2732.jpg -resize 1536 -format webp -quality 80 -write 1536.webp
magick convert 2048x2732.jpg -resize 856 -format webp -quality 80 -write 856.webp
...
null: